# Rails - Why is HAML showing the full hash?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

View:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= full_title(yield(:title))
    =stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
    =javascript_include_tag "application"
    =csrf_meta_tags
    =render 'layouts/shim'
  %body
    =render 'layouts/header'
    .container
      =flash.each do |key, value|
        %div{class: "alert alert-#{key}"} #{value}
```

Controller

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "This is Correct"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:wrong] = "no"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Regardless of the flash (:success or :wrong or otherwise) it always compiles the entire hash as html (below)

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
…
    <div class='container'>
            <div class='alert alert-wrong'>no</div>
{:wrong=&gt;&quot;no&quot;}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have no idea why `{:wrong=&gt;&quot;no&quot;}` is being displayed. I've been staring at this terminal for hours. What's interesting is that the hash is being outputted with the `container` id, but not in the `alert` class. It feels like an indentation problem, but I went through several permutations with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `-` rather than a `=` when you call the `each` block:

```
-flash.each do |key, value|
  %div{class: "alert alert-#{key}"} #{value}
```

From the [docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/):

> It’s also possible to embed Ruby code into Haml documents. An equals sign, =, will output the result of the code. A hyphen, -, will run the code but not output the result.

So you're seeing the hash because `=` will output the result of the `each` block (the hash itself, i.e. `{:wrong=>"no"}`).

Comment: The [return value of `each` is actually the hash itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each), not the last result of the block.

Comment: @matt Right you are! Thanks for the correction, updated my answer.